# Convert fractional number to Hexadecimal in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function, hex, to-char

I have a table in database with fractional value-
value
14.65
45
7458.34
34.69
4.7
34

I want to convert this fractional value to hexadecimal.

But to_hex function only converts decimal value(14) and not (14.65).

Tried with to_char also-
SELECT TO_CHAR(15.33, 'X') FROM DUAL; --->output: F

I don't want to ceil or floor the value and print Hexadecimal number.
I want 15.33 --->F.547AE147

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain the logic of how you get from `15.33` to `F.547AE147` (in particular, how the decimal part is to be converted).

Comment: No, `33` (decimal) is `21` (hex). However, `547AE147` hex is `1417339207` decimal which does not bear any obvious relationship to `.33`.

Comment: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html
You can use the link above and check
15(decimal)--->F
.33(decimal)--->547AE147AE147AE147AE

Comment: Ok, that is where you got the value from. Now you need to [edit] your question to explain the logic used in the calculation to get the output value so that your question is self-contained and does not rely on a third-party source to be meaningful.

Comment: https://dyclassroom.com/conversion/decimal-to-hexadecimal-conversion-of-a-number-with-fractional-part
the link for the full logic for hexadecimal conversion for fraction numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the values into the integer and the decimal parts and use `TO_CHAR` on them separately:

```sql
WITH table_name (value) AS (
  SELECT  15.33 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT -15.33 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT value,
       CASE WHEN value < 0 THEN '-' END
       || TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ABS(value)), 'fmXXXXXXXXXX')
       || '.'
       || TO_CHAR(
            ABS(MOD(value, 1))*TO_NUMBER('FFFFFFFF', 'XXXXXXXX'),
            'fm0XXXXXXX'
          ) AS hex
FROM   table_name;
```

Which outputs:

> | VALUE | HEX |
> | --- | --- |
> | 15.33 | F.547AE147 |
> | -15.33 | -F.547AE147 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=88d70e9ec78695bd2c87f38c127522fb)*